# Get path of App_Data folder in the Seed method of EF migration configuration class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

How do you get the path of the App_Data folder in the Seed method of the configuration class of code first migrations.

I want to read from a file I've put in the App_Data folder and the Seed method runs after the update-database command. HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath obviously does not work because there is no HttpContext at that point.

Answer (score 3):

I got it to work with something like:
    `string MyPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/../App_Data"`

because `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`  ends at the "/bin" directory.

Comment: Only in prod maybe. In the IDE when debugging, `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` points to the project root.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick-and-dirty way to get you started:

```
var myPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
//to quickly show the path, either attach another debugger or just throw an exception
throw new Exception(myPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

@Rusty Divine gave a good answer, however maybe you will find this is better for you:

```
System.IO.Path.Combine( System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"\\bin\\Debug$", String.Empty, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) ,   RELATIVE_PATH,  "FILENAME.EXE");
```

For example:

```
System.IO.Path.Combine( System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"\\bin$", String.Empty, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) ,  "App_Data\\Init",   "fileName.txt");
```

In that way (using Regx), we make sure the only replace could be is at the suffix (at the end) of the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` String. If there is sub folders in the server path named: "\bin\Debug" they won't be replaced.

This solution is case insensitive, meaning "\BIN\debug" will also be replaced.

Moreover, you don't need to append the strings to one string.
`System.IO.Path.Combine` will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth... you need to do a string replace if you are going to use BaseDirectory in your unit test. But, this still has the problem that it uses the path of your unit test project so be weary of that if you are trying to point to files in another project. In this case you will have to hard code the path.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Replace("\\bin\\Debug","") + "\\App_Data";
```